# Fabricjs - Resize isn´t working correctly on object

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

i am using FabricJs, everything is working really smooth and good, but now i have a Problem and i dont know why.

This is my Code:

```
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="Rect width" id="rect-width">
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="Rect height" id="rect-height">

<button id="target">
Change
</button>

canvas.on('object:modified', function() {
  var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
  $('#rect-width').val(Math.floor(obj.getWidth()));
  $('#rect-height').val(Math.floor(obj.getHeight()));

  console.log(Math.round(obj.getWidth()));
  console.log(Math.round(obj.getHeight()));
});


$( "#target" ).click(function() {
/*
var objwidth = $('#rect-width').val();
var objheight = $('#rect-height').val();
*/
var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
var objwidth =  Math.floor(obj.getWidth());
var objheight = Math.floor(obj.getHeight());


console.log('Original: ' + Math.round(objwidth));
console.log('Orginal: ' + Math.round(objheight));

if(objwidth != '' && objheight != '') {
 rect1.setWidth(Math.round(objwidth));
 rect1.setHeight(Math.round(objheight));
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o0gkmjru/

Everytime when i Scale the Object and press submit with values inside the inputs, it doesn´t scale it to the size which was inserted.

Can someone explain me why?

Answer (score 0):

you need to tell fabric that it's time to render. Just add `canvas.renderAll();` to the end of the click handler and you will see the rect change size.

Comment: Thank you, but that´s not part of my Problem. When i select the object, press the button over and over again, it will resize it again. You can see it inside the console log. I think it has something to do with the values i get with getWidth/height - because if i do it only with fixed numbers, it will do it how i want it